# Why can't I create a CAGradientLayer using custom colors in ARC?

Tags: ios, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting, cagradientlayer

In the following code for my table view controller, if I use "stock" colors like `[UIColor blueColor]` it works fine, however if I try to create a custom color using RGBA values, it fails horribly and doesn't draw anything but solid black.

Is this because ARC is deallocating the CGColorRef before it can be used? How can I get this to work with custom colors?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    CAGradientLayer *selectedGrad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    selectedGrad.frame = cell.bounds;

    UIColor* colorOne = [UIColor blueColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:96/255 green:157/255 blue:227/255 alpha:1];
    UIColor* colorTwo = [UIColor greenColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:54/255 green:123/255 blue:201/255 alpha:1];

    NSArray* colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, nil];

    selectedGrad.colors = colors;
    selectedGrad.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@(0.0), @(1.0), nil];

    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
    [cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:selectedGrad atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Just as a sanity check, make sure that `cell.selectedBackgroundView` is not nil after you set it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `96/255` it interprets the values as int, resulting in 0

Try writing the values as `96.0/255.0` when creating the UIColor

Comment: Aggh. I thought the compiler would be smarter. :/ Too used to living in JavaScript/C# I guess.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way for add RGB colors:

```
 [UIColor colorWithRed:0x63/255.0 green:0x4E/255.0 blue:0x42/255.0 alpha:1]
```